# How upload image with volley android to MVC api post method?

Tags: android, api, post, upload, android-volley

How upload image with volley android to MVC api post method.I have tried this :

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String responec) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Log.e("tag","data :"+responec);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Log.e("tag","data :"+volleyError.toString());
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

how can I handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the thing in one of my project that I had faced with several years ago and I just remind it and  maybe can help you: 
I writ this class to upload an image with a MVC API:

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Custom request to make multipart header and upload file.
 * <p>
 * Created by vahid on 27/04/2017 12.05.
 */
public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
    private final String twoHyphens = "--";
    private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    private Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private Map<String, String> mHeaders;

    /**
     * Default constructor with predefined header and post method.
     *
     * @param url           request destination
     * @param headers       predefined custom header
     * @param listener      on success achieved 200 code from request
     * @param errorListener on error http or library timeout
     */
    public VolleyMultipartRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener); this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener; this.mHeaders = headers;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with option method and default header configuration.
     *
     * @param method        method for now accept POST and GET only
     * @param url           request destination
     * @param listener      on success event handler
     * @param errorListener on error event handler
     */
    public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener); this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        try {
            // populate text payload
            Map<String, String> params = getParams();
            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
            }

            // populate data byte payload
            Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
            if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
                dataParse(dos, data);
            }

            // close multipart form data after text and file data
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } return null;
    }

    /**
     * Custom method handle data payload.
     *
     * @return Map data part label with data byte
     * @throws AuthFailureError
     */
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(response, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    /**
     * Parse string map into data output stream by key and value.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param params           string inputs collection
     * @param encoding         encode the inputs, default UTF-8
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse data into data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle file attachment
     * @param data             loop through data
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, DataPart> data) throws IOException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, DataPart> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write string data into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param parameterName    name of input
     * @param parameterValue   value of input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Write data file into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle data parsing
     * @param dataFile         data byte as DataPart from collection
     * @param inputName        name of data input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
        if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
        } dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Simple data container use for passing byte file
     */
    public class DataPart {
        private String fileName;
        private byte[] content;
        private String type;
        /**
         * Default data part
         */
        public DataPart() {
        }

        /**
         * Constructor with data.
         *
         * @param name label of data
         * @param data byte data
         */
        public DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
            fileName = name; content = data;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor with mime data type.
         *
         * @param name     label of data
         * @param data     byte data
         * @param mimeType mime data like "image/jpeg"
         */
        public DataPart(String name, byte[] data, String mimeType) {
            fileName = name; content = data; type = mimeType;
        }

        /**
         * Getter file name.
         *
         * @return file name
         */
        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        /**
         * Setter file name.
         *
         * @param fileName string file name
         */
        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        /**
         * Getter content.
         *
         * @return byte file data
         */
        public byte[] getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        /**
         * Setter content.
         *
         * @param content byte file data
         */
        public void setContent(byte[] content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        /**
         * Getter mime type.
         *
         * @return mime type
         */
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        /**
         * Setter mime type.
         *
         * @param type mime type
         */
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

and with this method you can use and upload anything :

```
private void uploadFile(final Drawable drawable, final String filePath, final String fileName, final String fileType, String url, final String mmtype) {
        VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String resultResponse = new String(response.data);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultResponse);
                    String type_of_file = jsonObject.getString("type");
                    if (type_of_file.matches("Voice")) {

                    } else if (type_of_file.matches("Video")) {

                    } else if (type_of_file.matches("Image")) {
                        url_uploaded_image.add(url_uploaded_image.size(), resultResponse);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
//                Log.e("tag", "response :" + resultResponse);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("tag", "error :" + error.toString());

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                return params;

            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                Log.e("tag", "data :" + params.toString());
                params.put("", new DataPart(fileName + fileType, AppHelper.getFileDataFromFile(filePath)));
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(G.context);
        mRequestQueue.add(multipartRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For me i always encode the bitmap to a base64 
using

```
public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

then send the base64 to your API ,,

in reverse mode decode the base64 and show the image using

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
{
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
}
```

`ImageViewObject.setImageBitmap();`